# Google sheets doesn't autofill dates

Tags: google-sheets

In google sheets, I wrote 2 dates, highlighted them and dragged down the little box in the right bottom corner and I get this:

[image]

This is completely wrong, I want it to generate the next dates, instead of repeating the ones I already wrote, how do I do this?

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### How does fill-down work with text strings, numbers, dates and formulas?

The fill-down feature, also known as drag-down an copy-down, lets you continue a series of numbers, text strings or dates across the selected cells. If the values do not form a series, the list of values will *repeat* rather than increment.

For example, a text string like `test 1` can be filled down to get

```
test 1
test 2
test 3
test 4
...
```

The numbers `1` and `3` start a series that can be filled down to get

```
1
3
5
7
...
```

Note that you need to select *at least two cells* next to each other before you grab the handle.

The dates `2023-01-01` and `2023-01-08` start a series that can be filled down to get

```
2023-01-01
2023-01-08
2023-01-15
2023-01-22
2023-01-29
2023-02-05
...
```

**Formulas**, however, never *continue* but always *repeat* when filled down. When a formula repeats, the range references in the formula get incremented, and you can choose which references get changed and which stay the same. See [absolute and relative references](https://edu.gcfglobal.org/en/googlespreadsheets/types-of-cell-references/1/) to understand how that works.

The fill-down described in the question will work fine when the cells contain valid dates. If the cells contains one or more formulas instead, the formulas get *repeated*. To get an incrementing series of dates through a formula, use this pattern:

```
=arrayformula( to_date( sequence(10, 1, "2023-01-01") ) )
```

When filling down date values, one particular pitfall is that the values need to be valid numerical dates rather than text strings that just look like dates. This often causes trouble when the spreadsheet's locale uses one date format such as `m/d/yyyy`, but the dates you enter are in another date format such as `d/m/yyyy`.

When date formats are mismatched like that, and you try to enter the date 5 January 2023 as `5/1/2023`, it will show that way in the cell, but the value in the cell will actually equal 1 May 2023.

Further, if the spreadsheet uses the `d/m/yyyy` date format, 12/31/2022 will not be interpreted as a date, because there is no month `31`. The value will get stored as a text string instead.

Always set **File > Settings > Locale** to a locale that matches the date format you want to use. Also consider using the [ISO8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard date format `yyyy-mm-dd` consistently everywhere. It works in any locale.

Also see [Automatically create a series or list](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/75509).

Comment: No, I wrote a formula =DATE(year, month, date) and 31/12/2022 is how the spreadsheet chooses to display it.

Comment: Edited the answer to explain how formulas behave when you fill them down.