# Google Sheet to fill in the inflation numbers?

Tags: google-sheets, google-docs

Is it possible so that, in the year 1992, I put in a salary of $38,000, and in the year 2023, I put in the salary of $123,000.

Now in between 1992 and 2023, there are many rows, for the year 1993, 1994, ..., 2022.

Is there a way to have Google Sheet automatically "fill in" the numbers in between according to constant inflation?   I know I can use a formula, but I am looking for some kind of drag a region and autofill method.

Comment: Does [this answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/171128/) address your question?

Answer (score 1):

You can [fill in](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/75509) the numbers by dragging a handle, *provided* that you already know how much the salary should increment each year.

Since discovering the increment involves a calculation, i.e., a formula, it would probably make sense to use a formula for the whole thing.

To fill a range of two columns with years and evenly incrementing numbers from the given start and end values, use a formula like this:

```
=let( 
  yearStart, 1992, yearEnd, 2023, 
  valueStart, 38000, valueEnd, 123000, 
  numYears, yearEnd - yearStart + 1, 
  increment, (valueEnd - valueStart) / (numYears - 1), 
  years, sequence(numYears, 1, yearStart), 
  format_, lambda(n, query({n}, "format Col1 '$0.00' ", 0)), 
  series, map(years, lambda(y, valueStart + (y - yearStart) * increment)), 
  hstack(years, map(series, format_)) 
)
```

See [How does fill-down work with text strings, numbers, dates and formulas?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/168485/269219)

Comment: so complicated... I can use `(123000 / 38000.0) ** (1/(2023 - 1992.0)) - 1
 => 0.03756902737047341` and so use 3.7569% as the factor to multiply each year for the increase (essentially multiply by `1.03756902737047341` but don't want to do it manually each time

Comment: Why would it be too complicated to paste a formula in a cell?

Answer (score 0):

### Formula in `A2`

```
={A1+1,B1*(123000/38000)^(1/(2023-1992))}
```

You could also use absolute references to the start/end salary/year instead of the values

```
={A1+1,B1*($B$32/$B$1)^(1/($A$32-$A$1))}
```

[image]

### ARRAYFORMULA

Similar to [@doubleunary's answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/171109) I think this is an excellent candidate for a one-cell solution.

##### Values in ARRAYFORMULA

In this formula, the hardcoded values for `sy, sv, ey, ev` are in the formula itself, but they could also be replaced by references to cells containing those values.

```
=LET(sy,1992, sv,38000, ey,2023, ev,123000,
  yrs,ey-sy, seq,SEQUENCE(1+yrs,1,0),
  ARRAYFORMULA({seq+sy, ev/((ev/sv)^(1/(yrs)))^(yrs-seq)}))
```

###### ARRAYFORMULA with Named Ranges

This next formula uses Named Ranges based on the following table:

| Name | Reference |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| sy | `E2` | Starting Year |
| sv | `F2` | Starting Value |
| ey | `E3` | Ending Year |
| ev | `F3` | Ending Value |

```
=LET(seq,SEQUENCE(1+ey-sy,1,0), ARRAYFORMULA({seq+sy, 
   ev/((ev/sv)^(1/(ey-sy)))^(ey-sy-seq)}))
```

[image]